# Drupal + Pathauto + services (json)

Tags: json, drupal

I using the [services](http://drupal.org/project/services) module and output in json format by `http://localhost/?q=mb_services/node/1.json`

And now I also enabled the pathauto and alias the node/1 to a-content.

My question is what is the correct url to access the json? I tried `http://localhost/?q=mb_services/a-content.json` but doesn't work.

Comment: I dont think the alis system works like that, have you tried creating an alias including the .json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

path is :

http://"your domain name"/"your rest service path"/?q="your resource path"/system/connect.json